# How to get header from the server? Retrofit 2

Tags: android, header, retrofit2

When I'm logging to my server I should get the respond with "x-auth-token" but I don't know how?

In Java it was simply:

token = urlConnection.getHeaderField("x-auth-token");

I have tried already like that:

```
LoginService loginService = ServiceGenerator.createService(LoginService.class,loginEmail,loginPassword);
                Call<User> call = loginService.basicLogin();
                call.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {


                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {


                        okhttp3.Headers headers = response.headers();
                        String token = response.headers().get("x-auth-token");
                        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "My token is" + token);



                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"You have been logged", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

After that I'm getting response , that my x-auth-token = null;

Comment: Have you tried something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30778141/4450805 ?