# Use Retrofit to download cookie as file, then forward the cookie again as file

Tags: android, retrofit2

Previously, I'm using bash script to perform the following operation

### Visit site and save cookie in file "/tmp/cookie-file"

```
curl --cookie-jar /tmp/cookie-file https://www.some-site.com
```

The downloaded `/tmp/cookie-file` will look like the following

```
# Netscape HTTP Cookie File
# http://curl.haxx.se/docs/http-cookies.html
# This file was generated by libcurl! Edit at your own risk.

.some-site.com     TRUE    /       FALSE   1564858012      B       6tbvhitdm98os&b=3&s=q2
```

### Then, visit same site again, along with previous downloaded cookie file

```
curl --cookie /tmp/cookie-file https://www.some-site.com/some-api
```

---

Now, I would like to perform same operation. But using Android. All the while, I'm using `Retrofit` library.

May I know, in `Retrofit`, how can we download cookie to a temporary file, and again making another HTTP request, along with previous downloaded cookie file?

Comment: Cookies are just some special headers. get them like  https://stackoverflow.com/a/36441369/4907678. Cache them with sharedPref or sth else and add them like any other header with OkHttp interceptors.

Answer (score 0):

Retrofit is backed by OKHttp and OKHttp accepts interceptors for requests, so you can implement an intercept to get and add cookies as showed here: https://gist.github.com/tsuharesu/cbfd8f02d46498b01f1b

To keep the answer consistent I will copy the code above:

```
public class AddCookiesInterceptor implements Interceptor {

    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request.Builder builder = chain.request().newBuilder();
        HashSet<String> preferences = (HashSet) Preferences.getDefaultPreferences().getStringSet(Preferences.PREF_COOKIES, new HashSet<>());
        for (String cookie : preferences) {
            builder.addHeader("Cookie", cookie);
            Log.v("OkHttp", "Adding Header: " + cookie); // This is done so I know which headers are being added; this interceptor is used after the normal logging of OkHttp
        }

        return chain.proceed(builder.build());
    }
}

public class ReceivedCookiesInterceptor implements Interceptor {
    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Response originalResponse = chain.proceed(chain.request());

        if (!originalResponse.headers("Set-Cookie").isEmpty()) {
            HashSet<String> cookies = new HashSet<>();

            for (String header : originalResponse.headers("Set-Cookie")) {
              cookies.add(header);
            }

            Preferences.getDefaultPreferences().edit()
                .putStringSet(Preferences.PREF_COOKIES, cookies)
                .apply();
        }

        return originalResponse;
    }
}

OkHttpClient.Builder clientBuilder = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
clientBuilder.addInterceptor(new AddCookiesInterceptor());
clientBuilder.addInterceptor(new ReceivedCookiesInterceptor());

new Retrofit.Builder()
            .client(clientBuilder.build())
            .build();
```

The gist already saves the cookie in the SharedPreferences and I think that this is your best option too. If you need to save the cookie in a file, let a comment and I will update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `cookieManager`.

Add this dependency:

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.6.0'
```

Client Builder:

```
static OkHttpClient buildOkClientWithCookieManager() {
    CookieManager cookieHandler = new CookieManager();
    cookieHandler.setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);
    OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .cookieJar(new JavaNetCookieJar(cookieHandler));
    return builder.build();
}
```

Add this client in retrofit builder.