# Android Retrofit GsonConverterFactory

Tags: android

I encode data on response .
put the key on header.
Now I can decode on Observer when I get string data.
But I would like to do on GsonConverterFactory
then I can just decode on gsonConverterFactory and use gson data when response
I would like to know how to get header in GsonConverterFactory responseBodyConverter?

Comment: provide your code, if you want help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add okhttpclient to your retrofit client for getting header

please refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30777419/getting-header-from-response-retrofit-okhttp-client)