# Check if the url is image with extension restriction

Tags: android, okhttp, android-glide

How to check if the URL is an image URL that must be either PNG, GIF, JPG formats

I see that it can be done with this code:

```
URLConnection connection = new URL("http://foo.bar/w23afv").openConnection();
String contentType = connection.getHeaderField("Content-Type");
boolean image = contentType.startsWith("image/");
```

But, I need to check using either `Glide` or `OKHttpClient`.

How to achieve this using two techniques mentioned above?

Comment: Why you need to check that using `Glide`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30777419/getting-header-from-response-retrofit-okhttp-client Does this help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are okay with the `HEAD` request I think that Jeff Lockhart is the cleanest solution. Anyway I post here below a more comprehensive solution about your question:

With **`okhttp3`** only

```
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.14.0'
```

You could check headers of an `HEAD` request also accessing body ContentType.

Check `headers` onto **`onResponse()`**

```
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    Request requestHead = new Request.Builder()
            .url("your tiny url")
            .head()
            .build();

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("your tiny url")
            .build();

    // HEAD REQUEST
    client.newCall(requestHead).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("OKHTTP3 onFailure", e.getMessage());
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NonNull Call call, @NonNull Response response) throws IOException {
            try {
                final ResponseBody _body = response.body();
                if (_body != null) {
                    final MediaType _contentType = _body.contentType();
                    if (_contentType != null) {
                        final String _mainType = _contentType.type(); // image
                        final String _subtypeType = _contentType.subtype(); // jpeg/png/etc.
                        Log.d("OKHTTP3 - media content type", _contentType.toString());
                        Log.d("OKHTTP3 - media main type", _mainType);
                        Log.d("OKHTTP3 - media sub type", _subtypeType);
                        boolean isImage = _mainType.equals("image");
                        Log.d("OKHTTP3 - I'VE GOT AN IMAGE", "" + isImage);
                        if (isImage) {
                            Log.d("OKHTTP3 WE HAVE AN IMAGE!", "yay!");
                        } else {
                            Log.d("OKHTTP3 SKIP CONTENT!", "Buuu!");
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("OKHTTP3 Interrupted Exception", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });

    // GET REQUEST
    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("OKHTTP3 onFailure", e.getMessage());
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
            try {
                final ResponseBody _body = response.body();
                final MediaType _contentType = _body.contentType();
                final String _mainType = _contentType.type(); // image
                final String _subtypeType = _contentType.subtype(); // jpeg/png/etc.
                Log.d("OKHTTP3 - media content type", _contentType.toString());
                Log.d("OKHTTP3 - media main type", _mainType);
                Log.d("OKHTTP3 - media sub type", _subtypeType);
                boolean isImage = _mainType.equals("image");
                Log.d("OKHTTP3 - I'VE GOT AN IMAGE", "" + isImage);
                if (isImage) {
                    final InputStream inputStream = response.body().byteStream();
                    final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                    runOnUiThread(() -> {
                        helloImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    });
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("OKHTTP3 Interrupted Exception", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
```

Check `headers` with **`interceptor`**:
Interceptors is good because it **centralises in a single place** where you check your url.

```
    OkHttpClient clientWithInterceptor = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(chain -> {
                Response _response = chain.proceed(request);
                final ResponseBody _body = _response.body();
                if (_body != null) {
                    final MediaType _contentType = _body.contentType();
                    if (_contentType != null) {
                        final String _mainType = _contentType.type(); // image
                        final String _subtypeType = _contentType.subtype(); // jpeg/png/etc.
                        Log.d("OKHTTP3 - media content type", _contentType.toString());
                        Log.d("OKHTTP3 - media main type", _mainType);
                        Log.d("OKHTTP3 - media sub type", _subtypeType);
                        boolean isImage = _mainType.equals("image");
                        Log.d("OKHTTP3 - I'VE GOT AN IMAGE", "" + isImage);
                        if (isImage) {
                            return _response;
                        } else {
                            return return415Response(chain);
                        }
                    } else {
                        return return415Response(chain);
                    }
                } else {
                    return return415Response(chain);
                }
            }).build();

    clientWithInterceptor.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("OKHTTP3 onFailure", e.getMessage());
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
            Log.d("OKHTTP3 - onResponse", "" + response.toString());
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                final InputStream inputStream = response.body().byteStream();
                final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                runOnUiThread(() -> {
                    helloImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                });
            }
        }
    });
    //*/
}

private Response return415Response(Interceptor.Chain chain) {
    return new Response.Builder()
            .code(415) // Media type not supported... or whatever
            .protocol(Protocol.HTTP_1_1)
            .message("Media type not supported")
            .body(ResponseBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/html"), ""))
            .request(chain.request())
            .build();
}
```

Using **`Glide v4`** along with **`okhttp3`**

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:annotations:4.9.0'
implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:okhttp3-integration:4.9.0"
```

You need to extend **`GlideAppModule`**

```
@GlideModule
public class OkHttpAppGlideModule extends AppGlideModule {
    @Override
    public void applyOptions(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull GlideBuilder builder) {
        super.applyOptions(context, builder);
    }

@Override
public void registerComponents(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull Glide glide, @NonNull Registry registry) {
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .readTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .connectTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .addNetworkInterceptor(chain -> {
                Response _response = chain.proceed(chain.request());
                int _httpResponseCode = _response.code();
                if (_httpResponseCode == 301
                || _httpResponseCode == 302
                || _httpResponseCode == 303
                || _httpResponseCode == 307) {
                    return _response; // redirect
                }
                final ResponseBody _body = _response.body();
                if (_body != null) {
                    final MediaType _contentType = _body.contentType();
                    if (_contentType != null) {
                        final String _mainType = _contentType.type(); // image
                        final String _subtypeType = _contentType.subtype(); // jpeg/png/etc.
                        Log.d("OKHTTP3 - media content type", _contentType.toString());
                        Log.d("OKHTTP3 - media main type", _mainType);
                        Log.d("OKHTTP3 - media sub type", _subtypeType);
                        boolean isImage = _mainType.equals("image");
                        Log.d("OKHTTP3 - I'VE GOT AN IMAGE", "" + isImage);
                        if (isImage) {
                            Log.d("OKHTTP3 WE HAVE AN IMAGE!", "yay!");
                            return _response;
                        } else {
                            return return415Response(chain);
                        }
                    } else {
                        return return415Response(chain);
                    }
                } else {
                    return return415Response(chain);
                }
            }).build();

    OkHttpUrlLoader.Factory factory = new OkHttpUrlLoader.Factory(client);

    registry.replace(GlideUrl.class, InputStream.class, factory);
}

private Response return415Response(Interceptor.Chain chain) {
    return new Response.Builder()
            .code(415) // Media type not supported... or whatever
            .protocol(Protocol.HTTP_1_1)
            .message("Media type not supported")
            .body(ResponseBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/html"), ""))
            .request(chain.request())
            .build();
}
```

Then calling

```
Glide.with(this)
            .load("your tini url")
            .into(helloImageView);
```

You enter your `okhttp` `client` `interceptor` and you can act accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

If all you want to do is check the `Content-Type` of a URL, without actually downloading the content, an [HTTP HEAD request](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html) would be appropriate.

> The HEAD method is identical to GET except that the server MUST NOT
>   return a message-body in the response. The metainformation contained
>   in the HTTP headers in response to a HEAD request SHOULD be identical
>   to the information sent in response to a GET request. This method can
>   be used for obtaining metainformation about the entity implied by the
>   request without transferring the entity-body itself. This method is
>   often used for testing hypertext links for validity, accessibility,
>   and recent modification.

You can do this with OkHttp as follows:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url("http://foo.bar/w23afv")
        .head()
        .build();

try {
    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
    String contentType = response.header("Content-Type");
    boolean image = false;
    if (contentType != null) {
        image = contentType.startsWith("image/");
    }

} catch (IOException e) {
    // handle error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in okHttpClient you have to use below line as a URL and make API Call, if call successful then you can check your condition.

ex:-

```
 String url = new URL("http://foo.bar/w23afv").toString();
 OkHttpHandler okHttpHandler= new OkHttpHandler();
    okHttpHandler.execute(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you obtain the image string. you can simply check for that image url that ends with (jpg or png) using this String format method.

```
imageString.endsWith("jpg") || imageString.endsWith("png")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting "Image path" as a string then try this...

```
image_extension = image_path.substring(image_path.length() - 3)
```

then compare this **image_extension**  with **png**,**jpg** and **gif**