# How to read custom header response (json object) in retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit, access-token, interceptor, response-headers

I have an authorization api that returns null body but with access token in headers. 
I am able to read the *okhttp3.Headers* object and also get header names as  Set using

```
Headers headers = response.headers(); // response object of type Response<T>
Set<String> headerNames = headers.names();
```

But in the code the headers object does not show the custom header (access_token) returned as response. However, in postman i can see the custom header as shown below:

```
access_token -> { "Token":"adklasldalksdalkdask",
"Provider":"ABC" }
```

I am using interceptors to get the header as shown:

```
    HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.HEADERS);
    interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
```

Can someone suggest how to read the access token as part of the custom header in auth response?

Comment: have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30777419/getting-header-from-response-retrofit-okhttp-client

Comment: Yes, i seem to have tried that as:                                                        
           Set<String> headerNames = headers.names();

        List<String> headersList = new ArrayList<>(headerNames);                           Also this give me null object                                                                         
      String token = response.get("access_token")

Comment: Access token being a custom header sent by the api. Does that make any difference?

Comment: Sorry, I just notice that the custom header you post from postman is 2 pairs, Token and Provider. Did you try to get "Token" instead of "access_token"? Also, if you can loop tru the headers and print them, then I guess you can check if you're getting the custom headers.

Comment: response.get("Token") also gives null. Actually i tried checking the headers list in logcat. This particualt header                                                                                          access_token -> { "Token":"adklasldalksdalkdask",
"Provider":"ABC" } does not get listed there.

Answer (score 0):

First print the entire response, body, code, message, header(by logging or something else) and try to find a clue from there.

I would recommend you to read the API docs and see the type of request it is asking for.

Use Postman to check which one of the following is working:
1.form-data
2.x-www-form-Urlencoded
3.raw
4.binary

And then accordingly set the annotations in the method declarations in the interface.

eg: in my case it was taking x-www-form-Urlencoded so I had to mention it using

@FormUrlEncoded
@Headers("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded")

in the method declaration.