# how to get retrofit request headers onResponse callback

Tags: android, retrofit2, request-headers

I set the headers of the request using my interceptor like :

```
    @NotNull
    @Override
    public Response intercept(@NonNull Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request request = chain.request();
        Request.Builder builder = request.newBuilder();

        builder.header("Authorization", "[token]");
        builder.header("UniqueKey", "[key]");
        etc;

        return chain.proceed(builder.build());
}
```

and everything works as expected (seen and accepted by the server).

My problem is than I want to read these headers back in my app when the response comes.

```
@Override
    public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<T> call, Response<T> response) {

}
```

I use `call.request.headers()` but always returns an empty String[]. All other attributes (url, params, verb) are accessible, only headers are missing.

**I set a key in the request headers and basically I want to check this key when the response is received.**

Any clue why the headers are not visible and how I can get them in `onResponse()` ?

Answer (score 0):

One of [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30777419/getting-header-from-response-retrofit-okhttp-client):

```
List<Header> headerList = response.getHeaders();
for(Header header : headerList) {
    Log.d(TAG, header.getName() + " " + header.getValue());
}
```

is has to be used inside `onResponse` method. Another way:

```
// get headers
Headers headers = response.headers();
// get header value
String cookie = response.headers().get("Set-Cookie");
```

Comment: This gets the headers of the response (content-length, content-type, server, strict-transport-security)... I need the headers that I send in request.

Comment: you can create a variable with header value

Comment: True, but I have a lot of requests  occurring at the same time and storing a variable does not help.  Another option is to use a `param` in `request  body` but this involves work for each request so I was wondering if it could be done using headers.